# DescTools package output to word document

Tags: r, package, desctools

I am having trouble with outputting results using `DescTools` package to word document. Anybody was able to get output saved in a word document as intended in the package? I get the following error. Thank you in advance.

> wrd<-GetNewWrd()

Loading required package: RDCOMClient
Failed with error:  ‘package ‘RDCOMClient’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it’
Error: require(RDCOMClient) is not TRUE

> library(RDCOMClient)

Error: package ‘RDCOMClient’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] DescTools_0.99.8.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] boot_1.3-11 tcltk_3.1.0 tools_3.1.0

I installed RDCOMClient with no errors.

> install.packages("//tsclient/D/user1/R packages/RDCOMClient_0.93-0.zip", repos = NULL)

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘RDCOMClient’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

> library(RDCOMClient)

Error: package ‘RDCOMClient’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it

Comment: You say you installed RDCOMClient "with no errors", yet the last line from your install message is "Error: package ‘RDCOMClient’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it". Sounds like an error.

Comment: Since the [RDCOM homepage](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) hasn't been updated since 2012, your best option may be to install an old version of R. (If you're bound to this tool.)

Comment: I am wondering whether others also get this error?

Comment: `DescTools` is a relatively very new package and I don't think it will be dependent on a package built for old R versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading the source `.tar.gz` files from [the RDCOM website](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/), I was able to install the package by uncompressing the files and then using `devtools::install`. I'm a little out of date, using R 3.1.0, but it looks like you are too, so it should work as well.

Comment: I am giving it a try. It takes so long..

Comment: I couldn't get devtools::install do the magic for me. I just copied the unzipped contents into the libraries folder & magic happened. Now it is working.

Comment: `devtools::install` is not much helpful if you don't have administrative previleges on your computer.

Comment: Use the latest version of RDCOMClient_0.93-0.2.zip available at Prof. Ripley's site http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/ as stated in the helpfile.

Comment: `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/", type="source")` does it nicely.